# Compute eigenspace of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

\begin{bmatrix}-1&4&-5&-3&4\\-7&8&-5&7&6\\-1&3&-3&-2&3\\3&-2&1&-2&-2\\2&1&-4&-14&3\end{bmatrix}

a) Consider $M$ as a matrix with real coefficients. Compute the eigenspace of $M$ for the eigenvalue $2$. It is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^5$?

- For this question I should use the formula lamda times identity matrix $- M$ and do the arithmetics, right? Is it required to find the null space?

b)Let $M'$ be the matrix in $\text{Mat}_{5\times 5}(F_2)$ obtained
by taking the coefficients of $M$ modulo $2$.
Compute the eigenspace of $M'$ for the eigenvalue $0 \in F_2$ and for the eigenvalue $1\in F_2$.

- For this question, I do not know how to obtain the $M'$ matrix of $M$ modulo $2$.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guide:

- Yes, compute the nullspace of $2I-M$, that is solve for $v$ in $(2I-M)v=0$.
- Note that all entries of $M$ are integers. If you see an odd number, replace it by $1$. If you see an even number, replace it by $0$.

For eigenvector for the eigenvalue $1 \in F_2$, we have to find the nullspace of

$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 &  0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

Let me permute some rows,

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 &  0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Notice that the $4$-th row is the sum of hte first two rows and we can get rid of it.

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 &  0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Add the third row to the first gives me

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 &  0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Adding first two rows to the fifth and then swap the $4$-th and $5$-th row gives me

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 &  0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Hence the eigenvector is $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}^T.$

Comment: should i keep the minus sign (when I need to replace a negative number with 1)?

Comment: $1 \equiv -1 \pmod{2}$, we can just drop it.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. For when the eigenvalue is 0 I got the vector [-1, 0, -1, 0, 0] serving as basis for all solutions (I kept the negative sign)
When the eigenvalue is 1 I got the vector [0,0,0,0,0]. Do you have the same answers? Thanks.

Comment: in modulo $2$, there are only $2$ numbers, I find it strange that $-1$ is written rather than $1$ actually but I can't say that you are wrong. For eigenvalue $0$, I can find another eigenvector besides your current one. For eigenvalue $1$, note that eigenvector can't be all $0$.

Comment: I shall try again.

Comment: hint for the second eigenvector for $0$, notice that the second and fifth column share the same parity.

Comment: I still get all 0 for eigenvector 1. My matrix is 
$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    2 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
    1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
    1 & -1 & 2 & 0 & -1\\
   -1 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Edited to include the answer, note that in the world of $F_2$, there are only two elements $0$ and $1$ and $1+1=0$.

Comment: Ah, I see what you did there, very nice, thank you.